# Remove newlines between two words

Tags: bash, awk, sed, formatting, sh

I have a file that looks like:

```
name: charles
key1: how
are
you?
name: erika
key2: I'm
fine,
thanks
name: ...
```

How could I remove the new lines that between "key\d+" and "name:"? It should look like this:

```
name: charles
key1: how are you?
name: erika
key2: I'm fine, thanks
name: ...
```

I'm trying to use sed or awk but without any success. Is there any way to clean that lines?

Is there any way to remove the newlines between "key\d+:" and "\w+:"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this?

```
kent$  awk '/^key.:/{p=1}/^name:/{p=0}
            {if(p)printf "%s",$0;else printf "%s%s\n", (NR==1?"":RS),$0}' file
name: charles
key1: howareyou?
name: erika
key2: I'mfine,thanks
name: ...
```

handle the spaces:

```
awk '/^key.:/{p=1}/^name:/{p=0}
    {if(p)printf "%s%s",(/^key.:/?"":" "),$0;
    else printf "%s%s\n", (NR==1?"":RS),$0}' file
```

output:

```
name: charles
key1: how are you?
name: erika
key2: I'm fine, thanks
name: ...
```

Comment: Definitely the best way to go. +1

Comment: @iiSeymour (nice 2 see u, Sudo :-) ) thx for pointing it out. I didn't notice OP's output. added a check to add spaces.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;/\n.*:/!s/\n/ /;ta;P;D' file
```

Keep two lines in the pattern space and remove the newline from the first if the second does not start with a keyword and `:`. When a keyword and `:` is encounter print and then delete the first line.

Comment: This one is better as you haven't hard coded the labels.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate awk solution.

```
awk '
  {
    if      (NR == 1)                s = ""
    else if ($1 ~ /^[[:alnum:]]+:$/) s = RS
    else                             s = " "
    printf "%s%s", s, $0
  }
  END {print ""}
'<<EOF
name: charles
key1: how
are
you?
name: erika
key2: I'm
fine,
thanks
EOF
name: charles
key1: how are you?
name: erika
key2: I'm fine, thanks
```

Comment: This almost work, but is removing the newline from one other label:
http://pastebin.com/aexZgH8F

It has removed the newline for the key label, but also the newline that preceed name1.

Answer (score -1):

The following works, but performance is obviously not the best:

`cat file.txt | while read x;do echo "$x" | grep -q ':' && echo; echo -ne "$x "; done | sed -n 's/ $//p'`

```
name: charles
key1: how are you?
name: erika
key2: I'm fine, thanks
name: ...
```