# Remove newlines in some lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed, formatting, sh

I have a file that looks like:

http://pastebin.com/a5Trnmyc

How could I remove the newlines that between "colaboracion\d+" and "organismo:"? It should look like this:

```
colaboracion1: - 3 a�os (2003-2006) adjunto al coordinador del �rea de Inform�tica de la Agencia Nacional de Evaluaci�n y Prospectiva (ANEP).- Experto evaluador y revisor de proyectos para la Comisi�n Europea desde 2001.- Experto evaluador de agencias de evaluaci�n de Argentina, Chile, Israel, Francia y de varios organismos auton�micos (Galicia, Castilla y Le�n, Andaluc�a, Murcia).- A nivel nacional es evaluador habitual de ANECA y ANEP (proyectos del Plan Nacional I+D+i, Torres Quevedo, Estudios y An�lisis, etc.).
```

As you can see, the newlines have been removed.

I'm trying to use sed or awk. Is there any way to do it?

It is not a duplicate question since this one includes special characters in the lines. For example, it include dashes that may change all the way to parse it.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not a duplicate question since this one includes special characters in the lines. For example, it include dashes that may change all the way to parse it.

Comment: Have you tried it with the solutions on the other thread?

Comment: Yes, but sadly those special characters are really annoying. That's why I have add the real input, I thought It would be more straightforward than the other one.

Comment: There's nothing special about the dashes or any other characters in your new input file, so far you've asked exactly the same question and it can be solved with exactly the same answer as your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/25099382/1745001).

Comment: @EdMorton I could do a major update in that previous post, If you think it would be better. I thought they were different cases (and I thought, in fact, that it would be a longer and more difficult answer).

Comment: I actually tried the commands there and none gives expected output specific to this question or to the file.

Comment: @konsolebox - I tried the answer to the previous question against the current input and it gives me exactly the output I expect. Coding1Free - I assume there's some specific way in which the previous answer is not producing the output that YOU expect so tell us what you are trying, what output you are seeing that does not match your expectations, etc. Help us to help you.

Comment: @EdMorton What answer did you use?

Comment: @EdMorton With `\r`s removed on input, this is the output I get with it: http://pastebin.com/aLfxMPs6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{ sub(/[ \t\r]+$/, ""); sub(/^[ \t]+/, "") } !NF { next } /^[^[:space:]]+:/ { if (length(t)) print t; t = $0; next } { t = t $0 } END { if (length(t)) print t }' file
```

Output: http://pastebin.com/mdx5uw98

Answer (score 0):

Stealing the regex bit from **konsolebox**'s answer, this should also work:

```
awk '{if($0 !~ /^[^[:space:]]+:/ && NF) printf $0 " "; else print}' file
```